# How is a branch converted to the master without merging?

Tags: github-for-mac

At the moment I only see the option to merge back to master – which creates lots of conflicts. But I don't want to merge, I want the branch to be the new master. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to either delete or rename (move) the current master branch. Then you will be able to move your new branch to be called master.

You'll probably have to `--force` when you push to a remote.